# Laravel updateOrCreate general error field post_id doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a views table in the database and i'm trying to update a record in it ( or create it if it doesn't exist yet) with this code:

```
$ar = ['number_of_views' => $number_of_views['number_of_views']+1, 'post_id' => $post->id];
App\View::updateOrCreate(['id' => $number_of_views['id']], $ar);
```

Unfortunately this returns an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'post_id' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `views` (`number_of_views`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2017-02-09 14:41:19, 2017-02-09
>   14:41:19))

It seems that it isn't recognizing the `'post_id' => $post->id` hence returning an error as if it wasn't set at all.

This error only appears if the record is to be created and not if it already exists.

Comment: Are you sure `$post->id` has a value when creating a new row?

Comment: Yes, I tried returning it before the statement and it's assigned a value of 8

Comment: I tried to set it to 8 directly, but it gives the same error

Comment: I suspect it's because you're passing two _separate_ arrays into `updateOrCreate`? I believe this means it looks at the first array as `attributes` and the second array as `values` (at least according to the api). So perhaps try merging the `$ar` array with the `id` array, then passing in a single array to the `updateOrCreate` method?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the `post_id` field to the fillable attribute on the model for mass assignment like this:

```
protected $fillable = ['post_id', 'number_of_views'];
```