# updateOrCreate not returning the 'id' column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

So, I'm having this problem for days now. Here's what I intended to do:

```
$premise = Premise::updateOrCreate(['premise_no' => request()->no_pendaftaran] ,
[
  'premise_no' => request()->no_pendaftaran,
  'premise_nama' => request()->nama_syarikat,
  'premise_jenis' => request()->jenis_syarikat,
  'premise_alamat' => request()->alamat,
  'pemilik_id' => $pemilik->id,
  'staf_id' => auth()->user()->staf_ic,
  'status_amaran' => request()->amaran
]);

$summon = Summon::create([
  'summon_maklumat' => $request->keterangan_pemeriksaan,
  'kumpulan_id' => $request->kumpulan_id,
  'premise_id' => $premise->id,
  'akta_id' => $request->akta,
]);
```

But now, the `premise` variable is not returning the `id` in this line `'premise_id' => $premise->id,` and showing this error:

[image: the error message i got]

But, when I refresh the page and resubmit the form again, it successfully inserted into the database. You guys have any idea why is this? I've been googling this for days now. No solution for now. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved my own problem. It may be less efficient, but, hey.. it gets the job done. So what I did was I overwrite the `$premise` by using `Premise::where('premise_no',$request->no_pendaftaran)->first();` to get the newly created object. The full code are as follows:

```
$premise = Premise::updateOrCreate(['premise_no' => $request->no_pendaftaran] ,
    [
      'premise_no' => $request->no_pendaftaran,
      'premise_nama' => $request->nama_syarikat,
      'premise_jenis' => $request->jenis_syarikat,
      'premise_alamat' => $request->alamat,
      'pemilik_id' => $pemilik->id,
      'staf_id' => auth()->user()->staf_ic,
      'status_amaran' => request()->amaran
    ]);
    $premise = Premise::where('premise_no',$request->no_pendaftaran)->first();

    $summon = Summon::create([
      'summon_maklumat' => $request->keterangan_pemeriksaan,
      'kumpulan_id' => $request->kumpulan_id,
      'premise_id' => $premise->id,
      'akta_id' => $request->akta,
    ]);
```

I know it might seems redundant but now it works. Im not sure I'm the one who do things the wrong way or Laravel's bug. There are other post that have similar problem to mine which was 1 month ago and still haven't been solved - [Laravel updateOrCreate general error field post_id doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140131/laravel-updateorcreate-general-error-field-post-id-doesnt-exist). So yeah

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in `updateOrCreate()` function when your record already exists and **updation** takes place, it doesnt return you the object of the row. It returns you 0 or 1.

And that's why when you try to do `premise->id`, its like trying to get property of a boolean which is not possible and you get the error because it actually returns NULL.

My suggestion is to go old school on this one:

```
$data = [
        'premise_no' => request()->no_pendaftaran,
        'premise_nama' => request()->nama_syarikat,
        'premise_jenis' => request()->jenis_syarikat,
        'premise_alamat' => request()->alamat,
        'pemilik_id' => $pemilik->id,
        'staf_id' => auth()->user()->staf_ic,
        'status_amaran' => request()->amaran
     ];

$premise = Premise::where('premise_no', request()->no_pendaftaran)->first();
if(!empty($premise)){
     Premise::where('premise_no', request()->no_pendaftaran)->update($data);
 }
 else{
      try{
         $premise = Premise::create($data);
      }
      catch(\Exception $e){
         dd($e);
      }
 }

$summon = Summon::create([
  'summon_maklumat' => $request->keterangan_pemeriksaan,
  'kumpulan_id' => $request->kumpulan_id,
  'premise_id' => $premise->id,
  'akta_id' => $request->akta,
]);
```

Comment: It makes sense. But, from the documentation I refer on DevDocs.io, it says it is returning Model class instead of boolean like you said. This is the link to that: [http://devdocs.io/laravel~5.4/api/5.4/illuminate/database/eloquent/builder#method_updateOrCreate](http://devdocs.io/laravel~5.4/api/5.4/illuminate/database/eloquent/builder#method_updateOrCreate)

Comment: Give me a min to check Laravel installation.

Comment: Meanwhile check my updated answer if it works for you.

Comment: Tried your updated answer. Now it is says this: Trying to get property of non-object. I tried doing this `$premise = Premise::create($data);` for both if clause but nothing works.

Comment: can you check out for which line it says that error?

Comment: sorry my bad, i forgot to take returned array in the `$premise` parameter..updated the answer with line: `$premise = Premise::create($data);` it should work now

Comment: line 225 which is this one: `'premise_id' => $premise->id,` in the `$summon = Summon::create([`.

Comment: now it says this: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'premise_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'summons' ('summon_maklumat', 'kumpulan_id', 'premise_id', 'akta_id', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (kjhkjhjkhkj, 91, , 74, 2017-04-08 19:18:14, 2017-04-08 19:18:14))`. Anyway, thank you for taking your time to help me.

Comment: I believe the new row is not being created in premises table and that is why you are not getting anything in `$premise` variable..try the updated code to be sure.

Comment: Tried that. Still getting the same error. I might be doing the old school way. Check one by one instead of using the updateOrCreate function. See if that works.